# excel vba filling array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, fill

I have the following problem. I have a userform with entry fields. The user is going to enter a number for participants. I have four groups of participants:

```
Group A: 5
Group B: 6
Group C: 1
Group D: 2
```

Each participant should be named like this: {GA1, GA2, ..., GD2} I wanted to write this into an array in that order and then use this array to fill cells with the names but all I came up with were four for-loops to write it into the array and that failed too. Is there a better way to do this?

```
Dim GA As Integer
Dim GB As Integer
Dim GC As Integer
Dim GD As Integer
Dim PartSum As Integer


GA = TextBox32.Value
GB = TextBox33.Value
GC = TextBox34.Value
GD = TextBox35.Value

PartSum = GA + GB + GC + GD

Dim NamingArray() As String

ReDim NamingArray(1 To PartSum)

For i = 0 To GA
    NamingArray(i) = "GA " & CStr(i)
Next i

For j = GA To GA + GB
    NamingArray(i) = "GB " & CStr(j)
Next j

For k = GA + GB To GA + GB + GC
    NamingArray(i) = "GC " & CStr(k)
Next k

For l = GA + GB + GC To GA + GB + GC + GD
    NamingArray(i) = "GD " & CStr(l)
Next l

'check entries
For i = LBound(NamingArray) To UBound(NamingArray)

    MsgBox (NamingArray(i))

Next i
```

Comment: Can you post the code that failed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see three reasons why your code isn't behaving like you expect.

First, the variables you use as indices in your `For ... Next` loops are inconsistent. In this loop, for instance, you increment `k` but use `i` to index into `NamingArray`. Note that `i` still has the value `GA+1` left over from the first loop.

```
For k = GA + GB To GA + GB + GC
    NamingArray(i) = "GC " & CStr(k)
Next k
```

Just use `i` for all your loops. No need to use a different letter every time.

Second, you try to access element 0 of `NamingArray`, which doesn't exist.

```
ReDim NamingArray(1 To PartSum) ' starts at 1

For i = 0 To GA 
    NamingArray(i) = "GA " & CStr(i) ' attempt to refer to NamingArray(0)
Next i
```

Third, your indexing is completely messed up more generally. For instance, `NamingArray(GA)` will be written to at the end of your first loop, and then overwritten at the beginning of your second loop. This happens for all your loops; their "jurisdictions" overlap (sorry, I'm Canadian). I've corrected this (and all the other errors) below. This works:

```
For i = 1 To GA
    NamingArray(i) = "GA " & CStr(i)
Next i

For i = 1 + GA To GA + GB
    NamingArray(i) = "GB " & CStr(i - GA)
Next i

For i = 1 + GA + GB To GA + GB + GC
    NamingArray(i) = "GC " & CStr(i - GA - GB)
Next i

For i = 1 + GA + GB + GC To GA + GB + GC + GD
    NamingArray(i) = "GD " & CStr(i - GA - GB - GC)
Next i
```

Now to answer your question: Is there a better way to do this? Yes. But this works fine, and though it isn't pretty, it isn't inefficient in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Why bother with an array?  Declare an int as a cursor

Assuming you want them across row 1

```
dim col as integer
dim Acount as integer (etc)
'get Acount, Bcount etc from form
for col 1 =1 to Acount
    cells(1,col).value = "GA" & col
next
for col =1 Acount to Bcount-1
    cells(1,col).value = "GB" & col
next
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

If the list isn't going to change, then your array might be simply declared something like this:

```
Dim participantNames
participantNames = Array("GA1","GA2","GA3","GA4","GA5","GB1","GB2","GB3","GB4","GB5","GB6","GC1","GD1","GD2")
```

If the list of letters and counts might vary, then you probably need a function, something like:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GroupIDs(grpNames, grpCounts) As Variant

Dim grpIndex
Dim countIndex
Dim output As New Collection

    For grpIndex = LBound(grpNames) To UBound(grpNames)
        For countIndex = 1 To grpCounts(grpIndex)
            output.Add "G" & grpNames(grpIndex) & countIndex
        Next
    Next

ReDim outputArray(1 To output.Count)

    For countIndex = 1 To output.Count
        outputArray(countIndex) = output(countIndex)
    Next

    GroupIDs = outputArray

End Function
```

... which you might call with:

```
GroupIds(Array("A", "B", "C", "D"),Array(5, 6, 1, 2))
```

Comment: I tried your code but when I try to step through array to see the output I get type mismatch error.

Answer (score 0):

Name your textboxes tbxGA, tbxGB, tbxGC, and tbxGD, and use this code to write to a range.

```
Private Sub cmdWrite_Click()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim ctl As Control
    Dim lCnt As Long
    Dim aOutput() As String
    Dim lTotal As Long

    For i = 65 To 68
        Set ctl = Me.Controls("tbxG" & Chr$(i))
        lTotal = lTotal + Val(ctl.Text)
    Next i

    ReDim aOutput(1 To lTotal, 1 To 1)

    For i = 65 To 68
        Set ctl = Me.Controls("tbxG" & Chr$(i))
        For j = 1 To Val(ctl.Text)
            lCnt = lCnt + 1
            aOutput(lCnt, 1) = "G" & Chr$(i) & j
        Next j
    Next i

    Sheet1.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(aOutput, 1), UBound(aOutput, 2)).Value = aOutput

    Unload Me

End Sub
```