# VBA Excel Date Generator

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if there is a way using vba or excel to make an array of each day starting with Oct. 10th 2010 and ending with Sept. 30 2015. Unfortunately the dates have to be in the format YYYYMMDD, such as 20091001 and 20150930.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Create a list in Excel:**

1. If you go to excel,
2. In the first top cell type `10/10/2010`
3. Then right click on the cell - and select `Format Cells`,
4. Then go to the `Custom` category
5. In the `Type` input area type `yyyymmdd` - verify that it is the right format in the `Sample` field (I had it set to `yyyymmdd;@` )
6. Press `OK`
7. Once the cell is highlighted, you can see a border around it, and a `+` in the lower right corner of the cell.
8. Click on the `+` and drag it down as many rows as you need to - it will copy the cell's content and create a series with each cell adding a day.

**Create a single row list in Word:**

1. Once you created that single column in Excel, in the column next to it, type `,` (comma), and drag it down the same way in order to copy it next to the whole series.
2. Copy both columns in Excel.
3. Paste it to MS Word.
4. In the lower right corner an icon will appear - `Paste Options`.
5. Click on the `Paste Options` icon and select 'Keep Text Only' - It is the 'A' icon. Now you will have a single text column with the number, a tab character, comma, and Enter character.
6. Open the `Search and Replace` by pressing `CTRL+H`.
7. In the 'Find What' input field type `^p` - it is the code for `Enter`.
8. Leave the `Replace With' field empty.
9. Press on `Replace All'.
10. Confirm the number of total replacements popup window by pressing `OK`.
11. To get rid of the `Tab` character, repeat steps 6-10 but search and replace `^w`.

[More](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214204) information about special characters.

*Related questions:*

[VBA convert range to array and format date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323704/vba-convert-range-to-array-and-format-date) 
[excel vba filling array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6383337/excel-vba-filling-array) 
[VBA Excel - Problems with a simple macro to auto-fill cells for a budgeting spreadsheet I'm attempting to make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21743834/vba-excel-problems-with-a-simple-macro-to-auto-fill-cells-for-a-budgeting-spre) 
[Fill two columns with random dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21360491/fill-two-columns-with-random-dates) 
[How to force Excel to automatically fill prior year in column instead of current year?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8745244/how-to-force-excel-to-automatically-fill-prior-year-in-column-instead-of-current) 
[Fill dates array and add dummy variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23664461/filling-dates-array-and-add-dummy-variables) 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277464/fill-dates-gap-in-excel

Comment: I'm still having a little bit of an issue, Excel still recognizes the cells value as 10/10/2010 instead of 20101010. I need to somehow get the latter version recognized as i pull it into a variant. Thanks

Comment: You can do Copy+Paste (`CTRL+C` and `CTRL+V`) of the cells in questions, and when you paste the `Paste Options` (press CTRL after the paste or press on the icon) have the option to paste as `Values` only (`V`).

Comment: I tried that and it will paste '40461' Excel's reference date number instead of '20101010'

Comment: Add a column with the formula: =TEXT(A1, "yyyymmdd"). Pull that down and then paste the values to a new column. The value will then be stored as text. If you need it as a number, highlight the column, use the Text to Columns wizard, and just press "Finish."

Comment: A quick work around can be done by copying the cells you want, pasting them into Word and then copying them from Word back to Excel. I just tried that and it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

For a non-VBA solution KingsInnerSoul's solution is very good.
For VBA, you could do something like this:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim arrDates() As Variant
    Dim dtStart As Date
    Dim dtEnd As Date

    'Assign start and end dates
    dtStart = CDate("Oct 10, 2010")
    dtEnd = CDate("Sep 30, 2015")

    'Create the array by evaluating an Index formula
    arrDates = Application.Transpose(Evaluate("INDEX(TEXT(""" & dtStart & """+ROW(1:" & dtEnd - dtStart + 1 & ")-1,""YYYYMMDD""),)"))

    'Example of how to access the array values
    MsgBox arrDates(1) & Chr(10) & _
           arrDates(2) & Chr(10) & _
           arrDates(3)

    'You could iterate over the array with a loop also,
    'or use any other array function, like Filter(), etc

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of an image, add October 10, 2010 (formatted yyyymmdd) in say A1 and HOME > Editing, - Fill:, Series...

[image: SO24895967 example]

for a column (or change Series in selection for in a row).